# PHP Write to a Multidimensional Array at 2 points in time

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working with a multidimensional array that I want to conditionally add keys to and am not getting the output I desire. At the core of the issue is the following code:

```
$data[$CSVKey] = array (
    'key1' => $key1value,
);

$data[$CSVKey] = array (
    'key2' => $key2value,
);
```

What I would expect to happen when I work with the array at a later time is that there would be a multidimensional array with both key 1 and key 2, but I am not getting that. when I work with it, I only see 'key2'. However when I change it to this:

```
$data[$CSVKey] = array (
    'key1' => $key1value,
    'key2' => $key2value,
);
```

I see the array as I desire. Can I not populate a multidimensional array this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing whatever value `$data[$CSVKey]` is each time you assign a new array.

You should just continue using your bracket notation to assign your values:

```
$data[$CSVKey]['key1'] = $key1value;
$data[$CSVKey]['key2'] = $key2value;
```

Or you could use `array_merge()` if you wanted to add more than one element to the array in one call:

```
$data[$CSVKey] = array_merge($data[$CSVKey], ['key1' => $key1value, 'key2' => $key2value])
```

Comment: Thank you - I know fully understand the correct way to work with multidimensional arrays.